# SML syntax is not recognised in Emacs despite having installed sml-mode

Tags: emacs, sml, smlnj, sml-mode

I have installed the package *sml-mode* (version 6.9) in Emacs (version 26.2) but when I try to open a .sml file I get the following error in the minibuffer: `File mode specification error: (invalid-read-syntax ?)`. As such, SML syntax is not recognised by the editor, which is also clear for the fact that the current mode displays the `Fundamental` mode other than `SML`.

These are the steps I did to set up my environment:

- I have first installed smlnj in `usr/local/sml`.
- I have tried to install the preset `sml-mode` package (M-x list-packages). However this did not work out.
- I then downloaded the content of `sml-mode-6.9.el` from https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/sml-mode.html in my machine and have installed it on Emacs (M-x package-install-file).
- The list of packages in Emacs displays *Installed* next to the `sml-mode` package, but apparently doesn't work.

Using M-x toggle-debug-on-error gives the following stack trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "?")
read(#<buffer  *load*>)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/Roberto/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.9/sml-mode.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 9890
load-with-code-conversion("/home/Roberto/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.9/sml-mode.el" "/home/Roberto/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.9/sml-mode.el" nil t)
sml-mode()
set-auto-mode-0(sml-mode nil)
set-auto-mode()
normal-mode(t)
after-find-file(t t)
find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer test.sml> "~/test.sml" nil nil "~/test.sml" nil)
find-file-noselect("~/test.sml" nil nil t)
find-file("~/test.sml" t)
funcall-interactively(find-file "~/test.sml" t)
call-interactively(find-file nil nil)
command-execute(find-file)
```

Comment: Something is going wrong when invoking sml-mode. Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` - that way you should get a stack trace pointing out where the error occurred. Then [edit] your question and add the stack trace (formatted as a code block).

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question with the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that there is an error at position 9890 in the file.  That is right next to a lambda character:

```
  '(("fn" . ?λ)
```

As this is the first non-ASCII character in the file, I guess the file was downloaded with a garbled encoding or something.  Not sure why `M-x list-packages` wouldn't work for you - I guess you'd be able to work around this by editing the file manually.  Compare to [this version on Github](https://github.com/emacsmirror/sml-mode/blob/master/sml-mode.el#L280) to see which characters are supposed to appear there.

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed some encoding issue with the file, instead of the lambda symbol I had another symbol. I had pasted the content of the file you linked and it works perfectly. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `M-x package-list-packages` did successfully install `sml-mode`, but subsequently it's not loaded.

Could you verify that the directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.9` exists?

The only configuration I have for `sml-mode` is what the package installer added:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

...

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 ...
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (... sml-mode ...))))
```

This should somehow reach the file `~/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.9/sml-mode-autoloads.el` which makes `sml-mode` load when opening the right kind of files.

Perhaps, could you also verify that `sml-mode` is similarly mentioned in your `.emacs` file?

I was using Emacs 25 and `sml-mode-6.7` successfully without having done anything but what you did. If I upgrade to `sml-mode-6.9` this setup still works. Unfortunately I'm unable to test that it also works with Emacs 26. I can unfortunately not say if there are any package manager discrepancies between 25 and 26 that could play in here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have indeed the folder `~/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.9`, which contains the following three files: `sml-mode-autoloads.el`, `sml-mode.el`, `sml-mode-pkg.el`. And this is the content of the .emacs file without comments: 
`(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (sml-mode))))
(custom-set-faces
)`